# Modify the elements of a Numpy 2D- array at specific locations without for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a Numpy 2D-array `a` and a list of indices `list_indices`. I want to modify the elements of the array `a` at each index specified in the `list_indices`.

The current approach I am using is with for-loop. For example, if I want to change the sign of those elements:

```
for index in list_indices:
     a[index[0],index[1]] = -np.sign(a[index[0],index[1]])
```

I am wondering if this can be done efficiently without a for-loop.

Comment: Give us a sample.  Are there any duplicates?

Comment: Do you know how to 'transpose' a list of lists?  `list(zip(*list_indices)`?  That should give you two tuples that you can use to index all selected points of `a`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change how `list_indices` is formatted. As you mention in your comments, `list_indices` could be `[[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]`. If you instead change it to be `[[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]` (first indices of the first axis, then the second), then this will work:

```
a[list_indices] *= -1
```

Or e.g. squaring them:

```
a[list_indices] = a[list_indices]**2
```

Comment: I get an error that `IndexError: too many indices for array` if I try this.

Comment: What are your array shape and list of indices exactly? That sounds like an error you would get if you try to access indices that are outside the shape of the array.

Comment: My array `a` is a 2D Numpy array. `list_indices` is a list where each element is an index. For example, `list_indices=[[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]] ` if `a` is a `3*3` array.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me if I define the arrays to be numpy arrays and then use numpy splicing:

```
a = np.zeros((6,6))
b = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,2],[2,3]]
b = np.array(b)
a[b[:,0],b[:,1]] +=2
```